# Pointer value modification behaviour

Tags: c

I am C programmer beginner and I have encountered something I cannot fully understand to.

Here is my whole code:

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>

#define DELAY 300000

int x = 3, y = 20;
int max_y = 0, max_x = 0;
int next_x = 0;
int directionX = -1;
int directionY = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    initscr();
    noecho();
    curs_set(FALSE);

    getmaxyx(stdscr, max_y, max_x);

    while(1)
    {
        // drawing on the map
        clear();
        mvprintw(y, x, "o");
        refresh();
        usleep(DELAY);

        // make next step
        next_x = x + directionX;

        //set next step directionX
        if (next_x >= max_x || next_x < 0)
        {
            directionX*= -1;
        }
        else
        {
            x+= directionX;
        }
    }

    endwin();
}
```

The issue I cannot fully understand is described on this picture from my debugging:

[image]

Please, could somebody explain to me, how is it possible to assign pointer value to -1 and receive +1?

Comment: It not the dereference operator, `*`, it's the multiplication operator, `*`.  Unfortunately, and probably incorrectly, C (the writers) chose to overload it. `directionX*= -1;` is the same as `directionX = directionX * -1`.

Comment: Oh, thank you, this may be the key!

Comment: @FiddlingBits What's wrong with the `*=` operator? It's consistent with all other operators, and unambiguous. In all pointer, contexts the `*` goes on the left of the name.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Nothing is wrong with it. I'm only saying it's unfortunate they overloaded the `*` operator.

Comment: @FiddlingBits: “Overloading” operators or functions [usually refers to the operator or function being different based on operand or argument types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading). The operation here is distinguished by syntax, and that is not usually called “overloading.” If it were, many operators in many languages are overloaded: parentheses (function call, grouping, and casts), commas (argument list and expression sequence), `-` (negation and subtraction), `.` (structure members and floating-point constants), and more.